# Move last character in line to specific column?

Tags: notepad++

I have a coordinates list,  and I'm searching for a way to move the last character (B) to a specific column (column 75). For example:

```
51 544598.83 5099537.14  117.54 404115B
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by column 75? Can you show us the desired output?